# Retrieve photo as image file using Get-UserPhoto

Tags: powershell

I can get "the user photo" from Exchange server using PowerShell like this:

```
[PS] C:\Windows\system32>Get-UserPhoto "Woodrow Wilson"


RunspaceId  : 1ce31a7e-bbb7-4056-98d5-39da1bdb677b
Identity    : exchange.contoso.local/Users/Woodrow Wilson
PictureData : {137, 80, 78, 71, 13, 10, 26, 10, 0, 0, 0, 13, 73, 72, 68, 82...}
Thumbprint  :
IsValid     : True
ObjectState : New



[PS] C:\Windows\system32>
```

But how can I get the PictureData as an image file?

Answer (score 2):

[This source](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/fb7c4cab-bed7-4e83-a1ed-9df7cbbc1143/get-users-photo-from-office-365-getuserphoto?forum=ITCG) describes using `Set-Content` to save an image from the `PictureData`.

```
$user = Get-UserPhoto user@domain.com
$user.PictureData |Set-Content "C:\Export\Photo$($user.Identity).jpg" -Encoding byte
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer provided by root is correct; however, 'byte' is no longer an acceptable value for the Encoding parameter (maybe as of PowerShell v6). The updated commands for PS6+ are:

```
$user = Get-UserPhoto user@domain.com
$user.PictureData | Set-Content "C:\Export\Photo$($user.Identity).jpg" -AsByteStream
```

Reference: [PowerShell Reference - Set-Content](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-content?view=powershell-7.2)

(Sorry for new answer - don't have the reputation to comment yet.)